# Raspberry Pi 3 How to connect to work VPN

Tags: raspbian, vpn

I am attempting to connect my Raspberry Pi 3 to my work VPN. I have a VPN address, user name, and password. I have tried searching how to connect to a VPN on the pi, and every search result I get is about connecting to some other VPN hosting service.

In not super familiar with how VPN works, but on windows I just enter the credentials and i'm done. Is there a simple resource to connecting to VPN on Raspbian that someone could link for me, or if its easy enough a quick explanation?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Surely your work has documentation on how to connect to their VPN. The RPi is no different than any other linux computer. Check your work documentation, if they don't have anything look at the company that makes the VPN solution. It shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a VPN client running on the Raspberry Pi to be able to connect to your work VPN.  One of the most common clients is the Cisco AnyConnect client.  There is a version for Linux that seems to run on the Raspberry Pi called [OpenConnect as explained here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/twiki/view/CF/OpenConnect).  They provide the steps to install and connect so worth a try. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot Ricardo. I was looking for this from ages. For other folks, here are the steps

1. Go to the link [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/twiki/view/CF/OpenConnect) and Install the package
   **apt-get install openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome**
2. Run the command 
   **openconnect -u *user id* -b *Server Address***
3. It will give option of group name to connect with
   Connected to HTTPS on 192.xx.xx.xx
   Please enter your username and password.
   GROUP: [CL-SL3-LDP|CL-VPN|CL-VPN-GFA]: ***enter one of group name***
4. Enter password
   Please enter your username and password.
   ***Password: xxxxxx***
5. Connected as xx.xx.xxx.xxx, using SSL
   Continuing in background; pid 3212
   Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS0.9)-(RSA)-(AES-256-CBC)-(SHA1).