# Connecting to work VPN on Raspberry PI need help

Tags: linux, vpn, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I need to connect to work VPN on my raspberry PI. I have been given ID, Password and server. Using Kerio Control VPN software on my windows machine to connect to the VPN. I cannot figure out how can I do that on my raspberry PI since I need to access some links on my raspberry. The only guide I have managed to find is the following:
[Raspberry Pi 3 How to connect to work VPN](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/65984/raspberry-pi-3-how-to-connect-to-work-vpn)

However, I am getting nowhere by attempting to use these commands :

[image]

Perhaps someone have more experience with Raspberry PI and VPN than me and can give me any sort of advice?

Since openVPN did not work for me straight away, I have decided to give it a shot using Kerio VPN client since I use it on Windows already.

I have downloaded debian file and followed the instructions:
https://support.keriocontrol.gfi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015190599

Initially, I had some error regarding the unmatched architecture:

```
package architecture (i386) does not match system (armhf)
```

Based on a quick google search, I have decided to try and add the architecture using command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

After this command, the installation of the Kerio VPN proceeded but still not fully,the full error message can be seen here:

```
 sudo dpkg -i kerio-control-vpnclient-9.3.5-4367-linux.deb
Selecting previously unselected package kerio-control-vpnclient:i386.
(Reading database ... 118878 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack kerio-control-vpnclient-9.3.5-4367-linux.deb ...
Unpacking kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 (9.3.5.4367-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kerio-control-vpnclient:i386:
 kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17).
 kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.9).
 kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 depends on libuuid1 (>= 2.16).

dpkg: error processing package kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u4+rpi1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kerio-control-vpnclient:i386
```

or the image:

[image]

Really appreciate any kind of advice!
I believe the issue lies here:

```
 kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17).
 kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.9).
 kerio-control-vpnclient:i386 depends on libuuid1 (>= 2.16).
```

But I am not certain how to fix that

Comment: You can't run x86 software on an ARM CPU.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead copy the text direct into the question: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Answer (score 1):

The software you are trying to load will not work on the Pi as it is compiled (created) for the Intel / AMD series of chips (that's the i386 above) and the Pi does [not use that](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/dlr0m8/a_surfacelevel_explanation_of_x86_vs_arm_or_cisc/).  *GFI* is not very good at stating the Linux chipset on their [documentation](https://www.gfi.com/products-and-solutions/network-security-solutions/kerio-control/specifications/system-requirements) but always look for the Pi by name.

I recommend that you ask your IT department for help as you do not want to create a security alert on their intrusion detection system and get your IP blocked.

You could also enquire if the firewall can be set to allow [IPSec security](https://www.gfi.com/products-and-solutions/network-security-solutions/kerio-control/specifications#features) and then use the OpenVPN client to access it that way.